# jQuery.get to read a file and use the data into a form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I want the script to do the following:

1. On page load, read a text file with a number (just one line)
2. Increment the number by 1
3. Insert the number in an `<input>` box of the form
4. Once `<form>` is submitted, write the number to the text file

When the form gets loaded again, it will rerun the code and the number will increment by 1. This is basically to pre-populate a field with a unique and progressive number prior to form submission.

I am currently using jQuery, PHP and of course HTML:

**HTML:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js">
            $.get("http://www.domain.com/tools/formdata.txt");
            function test(){
                $.get('http://www.domain.com/tools/formdata.txt', function(data){
                    x = data++;
                });
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="test()"/>
        <form action="save_json.php" method="post">
            Contract: <input type="number" name="contract" id="contract" value="x" /><br     />
            <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Invia" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['contract'])) {
    // if form fields are empty, outputs message, else, gets their data
    if(empty($_POST['contract'])) {
        echo 'All fields are required';
    }
    else {
        // adds form data into an array
        $formdata = $_POST['contract'];

        if(file_put_contents('/var/www/domain/tools/formdata.txt', $formdata))     echo 'Data successfully saved';
        else echo 'Unable to save data, try again or contact IT';
    }
}
else echo 'Form fields not submitted';
?>
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're set on getting the number in the file via ajax get, instead of doing it in PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: I recommend that instead of javascript, you do this with PHP `file_get_contents('formdata.txt')` at the start of your file, and then you echo it in. That way, the value will be there on load, rather than having to wait for the HTML to render and the javascript to run. Also, it is a much better practice and will let you do a lot more things if you choose to expand the page.

However, here's the solution to the issue presented:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var x;
        function test(){
            $.get('file.txt', function(data){
                console.log('data',data);
                var x = ++data;
                console.log('x',x);
                $('#contract').val(x);
            });
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="test()"/>
        <form action="aoeu.php" method="post">
            Contract: <input type="number" name="contract" id="contract" /><br     />
            <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Invia" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

The things to note:

1. Close off your `<script>` tag including the jquery library, then open another one after it.
2. No need to do the first $.get() you have - save it for the function.
3. var x = data++; - this increments data AFTER its value has been assigned to x. So, it will never increase. Do ++data instead, and it increments before.
4. You need to place it somewhere afterwards. How you had the input (value='x') is just trying to put the character "x" into the input. Use javascript to edit the functions value, as in my example.

Your PHP works fine.

Comment: Dear Logan, the solution proposed works perfectly. Will try also to use only PHP as you suggested. Grazie